QEMU ubuntu guest os RTC time (-rtc base=2023-0401)
I created an VM using the following command :
qemu-img create -f raw myVirtualDisk.raw 20G

qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm  -m 8G  -smp 8  -boot d -cdrom /home/danny/2T/tmp/iso-image/ubuntu-24.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso -drive file=/home/danny/myVirtualDisk.raw,format=raw -netdev user,id=net0,net=192.168.0.0/24,dhcpstart=192.168.0.9  -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=net0 -vga qxl -device AC97 -rtc base=2023-04-01 

after successfully install the OS, I start the VM with command:
qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm  -m 8G  -smp 8   -drive file=/home/danny/myVirtualDisk.raw,format=raw -netdev user,id=net0,net=192.168.0.0/24,dhcpstart=192.168.0.9  -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=net0 -vga qxl -device AC97 -rtc base=2023-04-01  

but when the VM is up and logged in, when I issue date command the result is still today , the -rtc base=2023-04-01 does not seem to work.
